# Is there a way to choose what DisplayFor renders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider this code:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeBoolean)%>

<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeInt)%>
```

First one is bound to a boolean this will render a disabled drop down list.
The second is bound to an int and this will simply render the result as text.

I would like the int to also render a drop down list too.

What are my options?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC has a set of default editor and display templates.  You can create your own by creating a DisplayTemplates folder in either the view folder for the controller, or you can define a more global template by putting it in a DisplayTemplates folder in the Shared folder.

For system types, use the actual type name and not the language specific shortcut (i.e. for `int`, call the template `Int32.ascx` or `Int32.cshtml` for Razor.

You can further specify templates by either using an overload (I know this is possible for EditorFor, I'm guessing it is for DisplayFor as well), or if you have a specific property that you want to use a different template for, you can use data annotations.

This same technique works for complex types as well.

Comment: How would i do this using data annotations? I know there is [DisplayFormat] but how can i get this to return a drop down list?

Comment: The UIHint Attribute.  Here is a good set of articles on both data annotations as well as templates: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html